# Firefox. how to resize textarea, inputbox, etc

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, css

is there any way or **addon to set size/force resize for elements(textarea, input,..) which are not enabled for resize?**

Inputbox elements can be resized from browser interface (mouse drag corner) when the CSS has it not disabled by rules or the property resize, for example:

```
textarea {
    resize: both;
}
```

However it is very uncommon to find forms/textareas which are enable to be resized.

I am aware that many pages can be resized, from webdeveloper;Inspector or Firebug/style, editing directly the property ***size*** in the sourcecode, i.e

```
<input id="input_username" name="Nombre" maxlength="140" size="80" type="text">
```

Following link shows how resize property work 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_resize

This is a question for pages in general. I am interested in an easy way to resize without coding, but dragging the corner of an element. As I said, I know that sometimes it is possible to resize changing code/style through firebug/webdeveloper/stylish but it is not quick or simple at all.

Comment: Are you talking about for specific web pages, or any page in general? Do you mean to be able to manually resize the page by dragging or by changing the attributes?

Comment: it a question for pages in general. I am interested in an easy way to resize without coding but dragging the corner of an element. As i said I know that sometimes it is possible to resize changing  code/style through firebug/webdeveloper/stylish but it is not quick or simple at all.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do accomplish that would be through the use of a *[bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)*. Copy the code below into a bookmark, and then any time you are on a page where you want to resize a textbox, click the bookmark button to make all textboxes on the page able to be resized.

```
javascript:
(function() {
  var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      boxes[i].style.resize = "both";
  }
})();
```

To create the bookmarklet in Firefox, right click on white space in the bookmark toolbar, select **New Bookmark**, and copy the above code into the **Location** field.